# How can user privacy be preserved in certificateless cryptography?

Tags: certificateless-crypto, data-privacy

In certificateless cryptography, how can a user preserve his privacy from Key Generation Center? If the KGC becomes malicious, how can the user's privacy be preserved?
I read "**Privacy-Preserving Decentralized Key-Policy Attribute-Based Encryption**, IEEE transaction on distributed system."

> In a privacy-preserving decentralized KP-ABE scheme, the authorities do not know the user’s GID nor can cause failures using the information of the GID.

And in Section 2.3:

> The global identifier could be the user's ID Card Number or Social Security Number.

I am thinking as follows :

While practically, At the time of doing registration at Decentralised authority or KGC ,user will provide his unique ID (like user's ID Card Number or Social Security Number which is Global Identifiers)
Now, Decentralised authority or KGC have user’s Global Identifier .

My questions are:

1. How the above statement is different from stated one? According to Section 2.3: "In a privacy-preserving decentralized KP-ABE scheme, the authorities do not know the user’s GID nor can cause failures using the information of the GID."
2. Please explain me Blind key generation algorithm

In this paper BlindKeyGen Algorithm is stated.

> [image]

I don't understand exactly how user's privacy will be preserved?

Comment: Does this still represent your questions well?

Comment: Com contains GID but it doesn't leak GID to A_i.

Comment: How only with the help of COM,the Authority will identify the user's identity.?Please reply me..